# Expand variable after patsubst returns name

Tags: makefile

I have the following:

```
FILE_1_DEPS := a b c
FILE_2_DEPS := d e f

output_1:
    mycommand $(FILE_1_DEPS) $@

output_2:
    mycommand $(FILE_2_DEPS) $@
```

I would like to combine the multiple targets, which differ only by the name of the variable, into a single line (the `FILE_%_DEPS` being left as is). I am thinking something like the following, which does not work:

```
output_%:
    mycommand $($(patsubst output_%, FILE_%_DEPS, $@)) $@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy enough, just look up [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
output_%:
         mycommand $(FILE_$*_DEPS) $@
```